# Exchange with Postfix MX for technical accounts in same DOMAIN

Tags: postfix, exchange, domain, mx-record

I have organization configured with Exchange 2007 server with many technical accounts.

I would like to migrate technical account to Postfix server with same domain

At the moment my structure is:

**Exchange server <-> relay exchange <-> Internet**

My goal is:

**Exchange server (name,surname accounts) +  Postfix server (technical accounts) on SAME LVL <-> relay exchange <-> Internet**

In other words, my goal is: *I would like to have Exchange as root MX - IF mail account dont exist in Exchange pass query to Postfix. If postfix don't have account then reject.*

I need idea how to implement such changes ?
What Exchange parameters are appropriate to get my goal and on which machine ?
Firstly I've set up postfix and stucked on smtp_fallback_relay, smtp_fallback_relay, fallback_relay

I have postfix 2.11.0-1ubuntu1 amd64  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Two servers are responsible for the same domain then? So you wan to configure one as public-facing and accepting all mails, but deliver some of them (either the technical or non-technical) to the other one? Which one you want to have where in the pipe?

Comment: I would like to have Exchange as root MX - IF mail account dont exist in Exchange pass query to Postfix. If postfix don't have account then reject.

Comment: Ok, so this question is primarily on Exchange, not postfix. Could you please write that also in your question above?

Comment: Don't do this.  Even if it is technically possible you are making a world of pain for yourself whenever something needs to be updated or goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks for introduction .. we've decided with chief we use another subdomain for it ;)